# how to sync windows time with server using command line?

Tags: windows

Windows 10 cannot sync the time correctly.

Currently, I need to open the "Internet Time Settings" window from control panel, then click the "Update Now" button to sync the time with server.

Is it possible to sync windows time with server using command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command line should do the trick :

```
w32tm /resync
```

You will find more doc on the windows time service [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/windows-time-service-tools-and-settings)

There was also *net time* but it's deprecated and should not be use anymore as it is said in the official doc above.